# How can I find the largest fields?

Tags: ingress

Right now, the Resistance holds >66M mind units.

Those must be from some fairly large fields in fairly densely populated areas.

But how can I find them? The Intel map isn't particularly useful for that, because it's too slow when loading fields and doesn't indicate when it's finished.

Comment: Is there not a status indicator in the bottom right of the screen that says if the map is up to date? I'm running the iitc chrome extension so can't remember what stock intel page has there.

Comment: The stock page does have an up-to-date indocator, but that only works when you have a populated map and want to know whether it's … well … up to date. But if you go to a new area, you can observe that the uptodate indocator shows up before the portals and fields finish displaying.

Answer (score 3):

In my experience, the total comes from many small fields. There are no exceptionally large fields, even if one is created, the opposing faction will make it a matter of pride to destroy it as soon as possible. This and the fact that it is significantly easier to destroy a field than it is to build one means there are virtually no long-existing large

Comment: I know that the total mostly comes from many small fields. However, sometimes there's a huge upwards blip in the number of a faction's MUs and I do want to know where the agents have been busy. By the time these things end up in the Ingress Report, it'll be too late (of course).